# How do I add images to posts?

Tags: support, formatting

How do I add images to a question, answer or comment. When I press Images on the top panel it says something like "Images are exactly like links..." and suggests adding the link to the image. But what if I just have a file with the image on my computer or even have it in the clipboard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When submitting a post, click on the "img" directly above the input box. This will bring up a dialogue box which will allow you to select an image from a URL or local drive when posting a question or answer.

<strike>To the extent of my knowledge I do not believe you can post an image in a comment. So only Questions and Answers will support this.</strike>

Comments can also contain images. See comment below by Oli for explanation.

- [Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/)

Comment: You can upload an image somewhere and [link to it from the comment](http://i.imgur.com/4cWJ2.jpg) using the markdown: `[text](url)`

Comment: Good to know @Oli. Cheers.

Comment: Silly I missed that, thanks ..

Comment: Note that you will need to have sufficient reputation (50+) to post images.

Answer (score 4):

## 50 rep + users:

Click the `img` button

[image]

Do you want to add from the computer or from the web? Chose here:

[image]

[image]

The image will be inserted:

[image]

My pronouns are He / Him

Answer (score 4):

At the Top bar of this image, there is a picture of a canvas (end of the second row of options). click on that and it will bring up another box (see bottom image). From that it should be quite simple to work out what to do.
Hope this helps (N.B. Click on the box to upload an image).
[image: Input box]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have some image data in the clipboard and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> while in the editor, click "Add Picture" and immediately, the image is in place.

[image: ctrl-v paste image in SE]

---

For super-fast copy-pasting a screenshot with Ubuntu, copy-paste a shot from full screen (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>print</kbd>) or from a bounding box (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>print</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

I set cursor in right place on text post, then Drag n Drop image to editor from Nautilus or Desktop..