# How can I add a screenshot directly from my clipboard to the body of a post?

Tags: support, image

I would like to renew / re-post my question about Bluetooth menu.

If I want to add a screenshot to a post, I can use gnome-screenshot and copy the screenshot to the clipboard.

**How do I add such a screenshot to this "body" of my post?**

In other words - can I paste it here directly from clipboard? Yes or no?

And if yes, how?

I have been saving screenshots in LibreOffice Writer files on my desktop and then adding the file here with the image dialog.

It works, but it's a little unnecessarily convoluted IMHO.

Comment: It's easiest to post URL's to screenshots I believe, ie. upload it to a site & post links here (sorry I've never asked a question here so I'm not the best person to give advice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add images to posts?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1396/how-do-i-add-images-to-posts)

Comment: Is what you're asking for possible in any online site?

Comment: @DKBose It is possible, I believe "*paste* an image" stands for pasting from clipboard.

Comment: @DKBose I don't think that is a good duplicate candidate for 2 reasons. First one, the other one is asking how to post images while this one is specifically asking how to post images directly from the clipboard. Also, the other question is very out of date as all of the answers are showing an old version of the image upload dialog which, from their text, doesn't mention that pasting an image is possible. While the new dialog mentions that, as pomsky pointed out in their answer.

Comment: @Dan I second that, but you pinged the wrong user.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can.

Either click the '*enter image*' button or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. Then it should get expanded as below:
[image]

Make sure you have an image in your clipboard and then simply press the universal paste shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Terminal menu bar]

Yes, both GUI “paste “ ( selected in mouse menu after right click )  or Ctrl +V works , however, not sure why there are still “instructions “ in the edited Body. They go away after "Add picture" button is used.   Sometime too many instructions are making things worst. BTW the objective was “from clipboard to Body “ - no “Image” button necessary. 
Now if I can figure out how to screenshot the actual “pull down” menus.

Comment: Please do not post follow-up questions as answers, even here on Meta. You should post a comment to the corresponding answer. If a comment cannot hold the content (code, image, long text), then [edit your question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/18733/edit) to add information. Keep in mind this is [not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) and the author of an answer will only be notified if you post a comment below their answer.